# Can I look at my hand after revealing my card and before I pass it to the next player?

Tags: sushi-go

After playing a card face down and flipping to reveal, should I be allowed to survey my hand a few moments before passing it to the next player? The rules don't strictly disallow it, but I've noticed it seems to be a general habit for players to face their hand downward before flipping, and when someone then peeks and ruffles through their hand after seeing what everyone has played (probably to see what combinations can then be obtained), there's often a knee-jerk reaction to consider that cheating in spirit.  It does slow down the game some as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rules state

> **After** revealing cards, pass your remaining hand face-down to 
>   the player on your left.

Technically, when you reveal your card, you should (or at least you're allowed to) still have your hand in front of you. It's safe to assume that it's not illegal to pause for an extra moment to look at your hand before passing.